# How to automate video capture for a game walkthrough with scripting?

Tags: shell, video-capture, video-processing

I would like to know how can I do an automated video capture for a game walk through on a game such as Second life, etc? I am using camstudio to capture the video. Using windows, I wonder if shell scripting, or otherwise can do the job with camstudio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to script and automate your interactions with a Windows application e.g your mouse clicks and keystrokes on the CamStudio UI, you can try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) (freeware).

The list of features from the AutoIt website:

> - Easy to learn BASIC-like syntax
> - Simulate keystrokes and mouse    movements
> - Manipulate windows and processes
> - Interact with all standard windows controls
> - Scripts can be compiled into standalone executables
> - Create Graphical User Interfaces (GUIs)
> - COM support
> - Regular expressions
> - Directly call external DLL and Windows API functions
> - Scriptable RunAs functions
> - Detailed helpfile and large community-based support forums
> - Compatible with Windows 95 / 98 / ME / NT4 / 2000 / XP / 2003 / Vista /
>     2008
> - Unicode and x64 support
> - Digitally signed for peace of mind
> - Works with Windows Vista's User Account Control (UAC)

Also try asking at superuser.com, there may already be applications that might be doing something similiar.